# Can we export entities from Azure Purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Following article describes, using [this Python SDK](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas) for Azure Purview and Apache Atlas, how we can [Bulk Upload or Update Entities with Excel for Purview and Apache Atlas](https://Bulk%20Upload%20or%20Update%20Entities%20with%20Excel%20for%20Purview%20and%20Apache%20Atlas)

**Question**: Using the above Python SDK (or some alternate API/SDK) can we also `export` entities, to EXCEL, from Microsoft Purview? If so, how?

**Motivation**: We performed our first `Purview Scan` on Azure SQL Managed Instance, `myAzureSQLMI_1`. Then we manually added some attributes to the scanned assets (Tables) such as description for each SQL table asset in purview. A month later, the instance name changed to `myAzureSQLMI_2`. Now Purview has two sets of assets with the same name but different qualified path. For example:

> mssql://myAzureSQLMI_**1**.123456789.database.windows.net/mySQLDb/dbo/Table1
> mssql://myAzureSQLMI_**2**.123456789.database.windows.net/mySQLDb/dbo/Table1

Notice here that the two Purview assets above are exactly the same (same database, same table). The only difference is that the purview instance (shown in line 2 above) does not have value for description attribute (since you have to manually add this value after the scan). We would like to have an automated process (some API/SDK etc.) that would migrate the attribute values of purview assets from old scan to same purview assets from scan2. After migration, we would delete the purview assets generated from old purview scan.

For the brevity of this post, this just an example. There are hundred of tables with multiple attributes (description, data owner, etc.). We want to automate the process.